# Changing color of a part of text of a Kivy widget

Tags: python, python-2.7, kivy, kivy-language

I am trying to write a program where if I press a button, the color of a part of the text of a Label widget changes.

For example, there's a `Label` widget with text "1/0". Now, if I press the button, the color of 1 changes to some assigned color. This is the program I tried:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.utils import get_color_from_hex

Builder.load_string('''
#: import get_color_from_hex kivy.utils.get_color_from_hex
<b>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Button:
        text: 'Press Me'
        on_press: num.text[0].color = get_color_from_hex('#04d3ff')

    Label:
        id: num
        text: '1/0'
''')

class b(BoxLayout):
    pass

class main(App):
    def build(self):
        return b()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main().run()
```

And this is the error I get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "b.py", line 28, in <module>
     main().run()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/app.py", line 828, in run
     runTouchApp()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 487, in runTouchApp
     EventLoop.window.mainloop()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 619, in mainloop
     self._mainloop()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/window_sdl2.py", line 362, in _mainloop
     EventLoop.idle()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 330, in idle
     self.dispatch_input()
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 315, in dispatch_input
     post_dispatch_input(*pop(0))
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/base.py", line 221, in post_dispatch_input
     listener.dispatch('on_motion', etype, me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:7699)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1030, in on_motion
     self.dispatch('on_touch_down', me)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:7699)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/core/window/__init__.py", line 1046, in on_touch_down
     if w.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:7699)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/widget.py", line 432, in on_touch_down
     if child.dispatch('on_touch_down', touch):
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 718, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:7699)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/uix/behaviors/button.py", line 110, in on_touch_down
     self.dispatch('on_press')
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 714, in kivy._event.EventDispatcher.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:7654)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1224, in kivy._event.EventObservers.dispatch (kivy/_event.c:13497)
   File "kivy/_event.pyx", line 1108, in kivy._event.EventObservers._dispatch (kivy/_event.c:12329)
   File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/kivy/lang.py", line 1557, in custom_callback
     exec(__kvlang__.co_value, idmap)
   File "<string>", line 7, in <module>
 AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'color'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Kivy's basic [markup syntax](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.core.text.markup.html) to set the colour, along with `markup: True` in the label.

Comment: I ran into another problem now. :\ What if there is more than one Label? What if I want to change the first character of multiple Labels together?

Comment: @inclement Where can I find a list of codes (such as `#fffffff`) and the colours they correspond to? What are colours formatted in this way called?

Answer (score 2):

For the second question in your comment where you ask "I ran into another problem now. :\ What if there is more than one Label? What if I want to change the first character of multiple Labels together?" You should open a new question and provide us with some code.

However, at first glance it appears that you could simply loop through the labels and do the following:

1. Obtain the current text of the label (label.text)
2. Update the label color by using markup for the first character. for example, if label.text = "my_text", I could highlight the "m" of the label text via updating the following inside the label:

   ```
   text = '[color=FFFF00]'+label.text[0]+'[/color]'+label.text[1:]
   ```

This answer assumes that you have a set of existing labels and you'd like to modify the first character of each. Without code, it is difficult to give a more specific answer but this general approach would work.

Answer (score 0):

[Inclement's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36668525/5446749) worked perfectly. This is the solution code for the kv language:

```
<b>:
    orientation: 'horizontal'
    Button:
        text: 'Press Me'
        on_press: num.text = "[color=#04d3ff]1[/color]/0"
        on_release: num.text = "[color=#ffffff]1[/color]/0"

    Label:
        id: num
        markup: True
        text: '1/0'
```

---

<sub>This answer was posted as an [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/36666797/3) to the question [Changing color of a part of text of a Kivy widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36666797/changing-color-of-a-part-of-text-of-a-kivy-widget) by the OP [Parthib Biswas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1952928/parthib-biswas) under CC BY-SA 3.0.</sub>